# use execl with some null arguments

Tags: c, exec

the program reads from a config file some values, some are defined, some are not, some have value 0, some are active.

I have the following code:

```
    char *arg1="", *arg1_value="", *arg2="", *arg2_value="", *arg3="", *arg3_value="", *arg4="", *arg4_value="";

    //part where I read from config file

    execl("./test", "test", arg1, arg1_value, arg2, arg2_value, arg3, arg3_value, arg4, arg4_value, (char*) 0);
```

How can I use execl but in case some variables are missing or set to 0 not to affect the others? I'm sure this is not the best approach by setting their value to ""

Comment: Isn't execv(p) a better alternative for this case? You could manually forge an array of arguments and pass it to exec in one shot ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that each `argX` is a switch like `"-xxxx"` and `argX_value` it's corresponding value and you always want to pass both if `argX` is defined. Then you could use `execv()` instead of `execl()` like that:

```
#define MAXARGS  4 

char *argv[2*MAXARGS+2];
int  i, argc;

argv[0] = "prog";
argc = 1;
if( arg1 && strcmp( arg1, "" ) != 0 ) {
     argv[argc++] = arg1;
     argv[argc++] = arg1_value;
}
// the same for arg2 to arg4

argv[argc] = NULL;

execv( "./prog", argv );
```

Comment: I had to change the code completely but now it's working just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Initializing arguments with default values and passing appropriate arguments(by checking whether the values are default or not) to `execl` could be the only option we have in such condition.

```
if(argv1 == defval_arg1)
         execl("./prog","prog", "required args in case argv1 is missing according to syntax of ./prog");
if(argv2 == defval_arg2)
         execl("./prog","prog", "required args in case argv2 is missing");
```

### Update

if there are more arguments to be checked you can simply use `loop` to form an array of args to be passed, by checking values of args.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){ 
  if (args[i]!=default_value_args[i]) { 
  args_2b_passed[j++]=args[i];
  }
}
```

and then use varient of exec function using args_2b_passed array. `man 3 exec` for more help.

Comment: that's a very nasty way to solve the problem especially when you have over 30 args.